# Does SO prevent users from embedding HTML image links to pornographic content in their user profiles?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, images, design

As far as I can tell, StackOverflow does nothing about this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If there's a user doing this, flag one of their posts for moderator attention and it will be dealt with.

Comment: AFAIK there are no restrctions on embedding images (or videos, on some sites) in posts or chat. If needed, flag for Mod Attention as "Other" or "Not Welcome". It would be difficult to tell the difference between a stack.imgur.com legit image and a indecent one. If you're thinking about trying it, don't. And if you're worried about the picture in your profile...well, let's see. (hint, hint, guys)

Comment: **This is what flags are for.** No one can think of every inappropriate thing that a user could possibly do. Human depravity is like that. However, some genius did come up with a universal system to address *all* of these potential problems. Try it out and see how it works. ;-)

Comment: @Cody Gray, how can I flag a profile image (not a gravatar). To see what I mean, click on the OP's profile.

Comment: Can you please flag a question or answer by said user for moderator attention and ask us to look at their profile?

Comment: @tombull89 - Said image has been removed.

Comment: @Moonbeam - please don't do that again, even to prove a point.

Comment: @Tim - it needs removing from his Stack Overflow profile as well.

Comment: @Moonbeam - I've also removed it from your SO profile for you.

Comment: @Tim, Gotcha' ;]

Comment: I'm glad this question is wildly unpopular. Makes me happy. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [Stack Exchange Network Content Policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy):

> **Sexually Explicit Material.** Accounts that use Stack Exchange to post
> sexually explicit or pornographic material, or links to it, will be
> suspended.

You can't flag a user, but you can (as ChrisF already mentioned) flag one of their posts and explain the issue. A moderator will then deal with it.

Answer (score 10):

Stack Exchange can't *possibly* do a skin tone analysis on every image that people post in their profile. Much like the rest of the features on the site, we trust you to behave professionally and in accordance with the rules.

If you fail to do so, we'll let you know. That's why we're here.

If you find something inappropriate in a profile, flag one of the profile owner's questions or answers and let us know what's wrong. We'll handle it :)